# Entity Framework code first migrations throwing error

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first, database-migration

Here is what I did before I got this error:

1. Installed EF (the pre release version, 6 maybe, I dunno)
2. decided I did not want, so uninstalled that and reinstalled the stable version (5)
3. Truncated my database via SSMS

here is the error:

```
Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or      
assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicK
eyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest   
definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from H
RESULT: 0x80131040)"
At C:\Projects\BCATracker.Web\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0- 
alpha2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:425 char:31
+     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodTargetInvocation
```

Here is what I have tried:

- Delete everthing from the bin directory, rebuild.
- remove EF from nuget, delete the file in the packages directory, readd ef in nuget.

Looking at the proj file I see this:

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

What could be a possible root cause?

Comment: Why are you having 3 versions of EF? EF6 alpha2 (6.0.0.0), EF5 for .NET Framework 4.5 (5.0.0.0) and EF 5 for .NET Framework 4 (4.4.0.0). What version do you want to use? If you don't have any other packages - manually remove all references to EntityFramework.dll. If you want to use EF6 remove the reference to System.Data.Entity.dll if you have one. Delete packages.config (if you have other nuget packages you'll break them). Install the EF version you want to use. (I wonder if the mess you end up with was caused by retargeting your project...)

Comment: I want to be targeting 5, for .net 4.0, which I thought I was, but since I added the 6 alpha briefly everything got messed up. What dll's do I need for ef 4.4?

Comment: Then clean up your project as I said above but don't remove the reference to the System.Data.Entity.dll. Make sure your project(s) target .NET Framework 4. From Package Manager Console run `Install-Updates EntityFramework` or use GUI - make sure you are not installing EF6. This should get you EntityFramework.dll 4.4.0.0 which is EF5 for .NET Framework 4. You should also be able to use Uninstall-Package now. When I want to retarget .NET Framework version - I always uninstall EF first, retarget and install EF again to be sure that I have the correct version.

Comment: very badly stuck in this very same issue!

Comment: This solved the problem for me:
The issue is happening because you might be having multiple versions of entity framework packages used in the project. Refer this:
**http://www.pinfaq.com/93/enable-migration-command-entity-framework-throw-exception**

Answer (score 18):

I figured out the problem. EntityFramework.dll needed to be in the GAC for Visual Studio to use it from the package manager.

1. Start Visual Studio Command Prompt (ensure you started Visual Studio as Administrator)
2. Go to your packages directory and find the EntityFramework package directory.
3. Go to lib\net45 (if targeting 4.5)
4. type: gacutil /i EntityFramework.dll

Note: It may be wise to restart the computer entirely at this point.

I'm not sure why Visual Studio stopped seeing the DLL, but this got me past this problem.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! it seems like, after windows 7 update i get this problem.

Comment: There are a few corrections needed to the instructions above.  1) You need to start the Visual Studio tools Command Prompt (usually from the Start menu under your Visual Studio installation men) instead of a general Command Prompt.  5) You do not need to restart Visual Studio in order for the changes to be recognized.  Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

I believe I could figure out a solution. I had several projects in my solution.

[image]

My database logic was in SqlDataAccess. The assembly was reference in WebUI.

I started off at the DomainLogic. Define POCOs for repository base classes there.

Then I added SqlDataAccess project.

and tried `Enable-Migrations, Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` command. It ran fine. After I added WebUI (an MVC 4 based web application to the project and ran the commands above. I started getting this version error.

I unload the project `WebUI` and re ran the command. And it ran fine again. So, Even if it's not the best solution you might want to unload other projects leaving the atabase project in the solution and then running these commands. It worked for me. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem while using using code first migration. just update the entity framework version to Entity Framework Version 6.1.3 to resolve this.
using command on Package manager console "Install-Package Entity Framework -version 6.1.3"

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Manage NUGET Packages for solution... window and update EntityFramework
2. Restart Visual Studio
3. Run the command in package manager console Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Movie.Models.MovieDBContext(This is a sample context)

Answer (score 1):

Install EF 6.1.3 and this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes above comment is right that worked for me.

EntityFramework.dll needed to be in the GAC for Visual Studio to use it from the package manager.

```
1. Start Visual Studio Command Prompt (ensure you started Visual Studio as Administrator) 
2. Go to your packages directory and find the    EntityFramework package directory. 
3. Go to lib\net45 (if targeting 4.5)    
4. type: gacutil /i EntityFramework.dll
```

Note: It may be wise to restart    the computer entirely at this point.

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd..

C:\Windows>cd..

C:\>cd \packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45

C:..\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45>
gacutil /i EntityFramework.dll
```

This will definitively works.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following actions to resolve this issue:

1)Uninstall Entity Framework from the package(Manage NUGET Packages).

2)Restart Visual Studio.

3)Re-install Entity Framework again from package manager.

4)Add reference to the System.Data.Entity.

5)Run the command in package manager console Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Movie.Models.MovieDBContext(This is a sample context).

After this you could see the changes reflected in packages.config.

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 10. The following steps corrected the issue

1. Open Program and Features and do a search for 'entity'
2. I noticed an update was installed on 1/23/2016 after the 6.1.3 update on 7/22/2015
3. Selected the 'Entity Framework 6.1.3' etc.. update
4. Clicked on the "Repair" button. After the repair completed I restarted Visual Studio and issue no longer surfaced.

Thanks to @Farshid for the initial clue to a resolution.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing same error and waste a lot of time on this error 
**This is only due to I updated entity framework but it gave this error so I again install *Entity Framework 6.0.0*  **
Error solved

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhuwu.png)