# Enable Migrations in MVC throws File not Found Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I'm new to using MVC, and when working through the tutorials regarding migrations in Visual Studio 2013 I appear to have broken the tie-in to EntityFramework in the Package Manager console.

I believe this started when I updated the EntityFramework to version 6.1.3, But that appears to be incompatible with the MVC Controller scaffolding.  So I rolled it back to version 5.0.0.

When I now enter the command `enable-migrations`

I get the following error:

> Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0
>       , Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
>       At      D:\ss\CAP\CAP_MVC_Dev_2\CAP_MVC\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:431 char:31
>       +     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodTargetInvocation

The file `EntityFramework.psm1` exists where it is described above, but the error appears to be in that file?  How is `$domain.CreateInstanceFrom` missing, and where from?  Uninstalling and reinstalling the EntityFramework package makes no difference.

I've tried creating new projects from scratch and this error persists across them.  An uninstall/reinstall of Visual Studio 2013 has not resolved the issue either, nor has destroying the connected database and starting again with an empty one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out the solution was similar to this one

[Entity Framework code first migrations throwing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832417/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-throwing-error)

When I first attempted this solution there were reports of gacutil not being recognised.  Due to the environment I work it it is not simple to add the gacutil to be universally recognised (I believe), so i found the gacutil.exe in the file system, copied that to the `lib\net45` folder referenced in the linked post, and then ran the command

```
gacutil /i EntityFramework.dll
```

This has resolved the problem, and i no longer receive the 'File not Found error'

Answer (score 2):

Instead of installing with GAC, I came to the following solution (VS2013 SP5 + EF 5):

Copied **(Solution dir)\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0** (entire directory)
to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\EFTools\NuGet Packages\
```

The NuGet Packages directory did not exist, so one needs to create it manually.

Comment: Thanks @spottedone! This solution works for me (VS 2013 Update 5 + EF 5.0.0).

Comment: Thanks @spottedone! This solution worked for me as well.